# Define generic type limit to nullable primitive types

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

Can I define a generic type with nullable primitive data type.
Something like

```
public class DataTypeHolder<T> :List<T> where T : struct
{
    public DataTypeHolder()
    {

    }
    public void DoubleValueWithNull()
    {
        var count = this.Count;
        for (int from = 0; from < count; from++)
        {
            this.Add(null); ////  **this is needed..but causing compilation error**
        }

    }

}
```

Later this should be possible

```
DataTypeHolder<double?> d = new DataTypeHolder<double?>();
```

Comment: Maybe `: List<T?>` (attention to the `T?`)?

Comment: Can't you just restrict on `Nullable<T>` instead of `T`?

Comment: example will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your class like this:

```
public class DataTypeHolder<T> :List<T?> where T : struct
```

which is the same as:

```
public class DataTypeHolder<T> :List<Nullable<T>> where T : struct
```

Comment: still compilation error. I edit my question please have a look

Comment: @DJ It would be a `DataTypeHolder<double>`, not a `DataTypeHolder<double?>`

Comment: But I need a collection of nullable doubles

Comment: DataTypeHolder<double> extends List<double?> so it stores nullable doubles. Confusing maybe, but true.